# How to redirect all bad emails to the one master email using DNS

Tags: email, dns

Sometimes when people try to send me messages they misspell email address and I lose the message.

Example:

If my email is `ivijan.stefan@something.com` and my client misspell and write `evan.steven@something.com` or `iivijan.stefan@something.com` etc, I will lost my email.

Is there a way to use MX record or some DNS setup to server notify me and send message on one master email address where I can see that someone try to contact me and see message?

Answer (score 1):

DNS servers do not understand what an email is. It may be possible to do this at your mail server end though. Look for documentation for catch-all email addresses to receive all email that would have been sent to non-existent email addresses. Note that this may expose you to huge amounts of spam from bots that target well known email addresses like admin@domain or postmaster@domain.